# using 'echo' & 'printf' in bash function calls

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a simple shell function call and I'm using `echo` and `printf` commands to print the parameter I'm passing. I have noticed the following:

1. `echo` is printing the output
2. `printf` is not printing the output

Am I missing something here?

```
check_host(){
    # prints output
    echo $1

    # does not print the output
    printf $1

    }
check_host $(hostname)
```

Comment: that works :) 
any explanation on this ?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function you show would print the first argument twice, once with a newline appended, and with *no newline* at the end of the of second output.

E.g. in an interactive Bash shell, you'd get something like this

```
user@foo /tmp$ check_host foo
foo
foouser@foo /tmp$
```

The output from `printf` *is* there, just not on a line of its own.

The difference between `echo` and `printf` is that `echo` prints a newline at the end even if you don't ask for it (you can prevent that in Bash by using `echo -n`), and `printf` works more like the `printf()` function in C, in that it only prints what you ask. You'll have to explicitly use `\n` in the `printf` format string to get the newline.

Note that in general, you'd want to quote those variables and the command substitution to prevent issues with word splitting. This probably isn't a problem with the hostname, but if you have values with whitespace, you'll need it.

So:

```
check_host() {
    echo "$1"
    printf "%s\n" "$1"
}
check_host "$(hostname)"
```

Printing arbitrary data with `printf` should also be done through the `%s` format specifier as above. Otherwise any `%` signs in the data would be interpreted by `printf`.

Also see: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)